# dynamically initializing a child component at run time

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4.5

In a current Flex project, i have an issue where a certain child component must be initialized and ready when the user clicks a button. the button is a mouseClick Event.

```
//mouseClick Event

protected function tableSearch_searchClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            parentXml = event.xmlNode;
            if(classifierInfo)
            classifierInfo.variables = parentXml;
            else //initialize it dynamically..but how?
            {};
}
```

in the function the component (classifierInfo) is checked to see if it is initialized and ready== that is, it is not null. then the variables property is populated with the parentXml value else, if it is not ready, [i want to initialize it dynamically] but do not know how.

does any one know how i could fill up the else statement such that the classifierInfo component is initialized dynamically? Is this even possible?

Comment: Is the classifierInfo on the stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to try to initialize the object and add it to the correct parent UI Object if it is a visual component.

```
classifierInfo = new WhateverClass();
classifierInfo.somePropertySet
...
yourUIComponent.addElement(classifierInfo);
```

Is it that what you are trying to do?